# Optimize distance calculations between 2 **long**, 2-D arrays of points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to avoid looping by using the 'apply' function to apply inline functions on all the rows of a dataframe.

The thing is, I have ~800 Points (truck stops), and I am trying to determine which of these are along some route, which itself is defined by ~100k Points.

My method is to calc euclidean distances between a truckstop to each point on route, and if any of these distances is less than some value I retain the route.

I initially did this by looping but it was super slow (assuming I don't break loop when distance less than some value, it is like 100k*800 iterrations).

So I tried using 'apply' but it is still slow. Does anyone know a way I can optimize this?

**FULL CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time, os

BASE_DIR='C:\\Users\\aidenm\\Desktop\\geo'

rt_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test_route.txt'))
'''
lon, lat
-118.410339, 34.019653
-118.410805, 34.020241
-118.411301, 34.020863
-118.411766, 34.021458
...
'''

fm_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test_fm.txt'))
'''
lat, lon
41.033959, -77.515672
41.785524, -80.853175
41.128748, -80.769934
41.465085, -82.060677
...
'''



def is_on_route_inline(x, route_coordinates):
    '''

    :param route_coordinates:
    :param fencing_module_coordinate:
    :return: True if on route else False
    '''



    a = np.array((float(x[0]), float(x[1])))
    # bs = [np.array((c[1], c[0])) for c in rcs]


    def distance_inline(b, fcm_point):
        return np.linalg.norm(b-fcm_point)

    # bss = pd.Series(bs)
    distances = route_coordinates.apply(distance_inline, args=(a,), axis=1)   #np.linalg.norm(a-b))

    # distances = [np.linalg.norm(a-b) for b in bs]

    if min(distances)<0.1:
        print(x)
        return True

    return False

fm_df.apply(is_on_route_inline,  args=(rt_df,), axis=1)#rt_df)
```

Comment: Look into `scipy.dist.KDTree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this quickly you'll want to convert the data from the DataFrame into a Numpy array. To start, let's compute the distance between *one* truck stop and all route points–

```py
# Create Numpy array of shape (100k, 2)
route_points = rt_df[['lat', 'lon']].values

truck_stop = # get one truck stop location shape (2, )

# Compute distances
dists = np.linalg.norm(route_points - truck_stop, axis=1)
```

This lets Numpy broadcasting handle looping over all route locations for you (very fast). However, it sounds like what you really need is the the distance between *all pairs* of truck-stops and route-points. Its tricky to get Numpy broadcasting to do this so I'd recommend using `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

route_points = rt_df[['lat', 'lon']].values  # shape (100k, 2)
truck_points = fm_df[['lat', 'lon']].values  # shape (800, 2)

all_distances = distance_matrix(route_points, truck_points) # shape (100k, 800)
```

Now `all_distances` is a Numpy array containing all pair-wise distances, so `all_distances[i, j]` is the distance between route `i` and truck stop `j`.  Again, this lets Numpy handle looping over the 100k * 800 iterations for you and is very fast. (On my laptop it took ~3 seconds to complete this with similarly sized arrays).

After that, you can find the distances that are small enough

```
all_distances < 0.1
```